# Using Javascript or JQuery to show/hide on click, and change image as well

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

I am trying to have a menu show on click of a bar on the side of my webpage.

I have a clickable div that hides or shows the contents already.

However, I also want the image to change on click as well and am having trouble knowing how to do both. At the moment I declare the background image in the CSS code, but I am aware that that probably needs to change.

This is the javascript I have so far:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

[The jsfiddle is here with the html and css in.](http://jsfiddle.net/KWxV2/)

I hope it does a better job of explaining than I have. Fire away with questions because I am failing miserably at explaining for which I apologise.

Comment: The code you have already done is vanilla javascript and has nothing to do with jquery. So you are looking for a jquery or a pure javascript solution?

Comment: Doesn't `e.style.backgroundImage = 'whatever'` do what you want?

Comment: sorry, either javascript or jquery is fine. 
I tried e.style.backgroundImage = and coudn't get it to do what I wanted... which is probably just my inexperience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get any of those responses to work, which is my fault, not the code that I was given. I probably didn't understand it well enough.

I have instead found a different solution. My image is now declared in the HTML, not the CSS and looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleVisibility(divID, imgID)
{
    if (document.getElementById(divID).style.display == "block") 
    {
        document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(imgID).src = "images/contents2.png";
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(imgID).src = "images/contents1.png";
    }
}
```

```
<div id="float">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('contents','contentsImg')">
    <img id="contentsImg" src="images/contents2.png" onclick="toggleVisibility('showDiv',this.id)"/></a>
</div>

<div id="contents">
    contents
</div>
```

Thanks for all your help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You want more-or-less something like that:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block'){
        e.style.display = 'none';
        e.style.background-image = "url('path')";
    }else{
        e.style.display = 'block';
        e.style.background-image = "url('path')";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he's talking about the background image in the CSS, not an IMG element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking solution with jquery:

```
function toggle_visibility(content, current) {
  var e = $(content);
  var curr = $(current);
  if (e.css('display') == 'block') {
      e.css('display', 'none');
      curr.css('background','red');
  } else {
      e.css('display', 'block');
      curr.css('background','#3E3E3E');
  }
}

$('#float a').click(function () {
    toggle_visibility($('#contents'), $(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery approach...

```
<div id="float" style="background-color: Red">
        <a id="linkID" href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="contents" style="background-color: Blue">
        contents
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#linkID").click(function () {
            $("#contents").toggle();
            if ($("#contents").is(':visible') === true) {
                $("#float").css("background-color", "green");
            } else {
                $("#float").css("background-color", "black");
            }
        });

    });
```